# How to import a Library Project?

Tags: android

I am interested in including an Android Library project into studio.  I get that its just a simple gradle change :mylibrary in the compile directive, but how do I pull this library code into studio? I want to see the library and also my app in the same Studio window. I don't see an import library option.  I see open project but then it seems to want to open new window etc.  How do I just import the damn library project?

Update, just wasted a half hour:
Hey Studio team guys, why are you hiding this under File ->New ?  What on earth does importing a library have to do with File and New?

Comment: Try ... File > New > Import Module > select your library >

Comment: import your library project in import module

Comment: This is correct. Thanks.  I think File -> New is really not where anyone in their right mind would put this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android studio we can use 3 types of libraries.

- Gradle which is easiest way to add,
- File which is called jar file,
- Module library which is another android studio project which is defined as a library in gradle.

To Add Gradle library you need to add gradle url in `build.gradle` at module level.

[image: Gradle]

To Add File dependency/library you need to add jar file into your project's lib folder and add it as a library.

[image: File Library]

As the most Module library can be add by importing another project as a module and set it as a library.

[image: Module Dependency]

How to add all this as a library?

You can go to `Project Structure` to add file and module as a library. on your project module (say `app` in my project) click `F12(For windows OS)` and you will get project structure. You can add libraries from dependency tab.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Ok, just to clarify I want to import the library code, and have it as a dependency :mylibrary  I am trying this now via the project structure ... let me see what happens just  a sec

Comment: It is called module dependency in android studio. Once you import project as a module you can add it as a module library. Rest will be handled by android studio.

Comment: Also you may need to do some changes in libraries gradle file if it is not already define as a library.

Comment: How about when you add :mylibrary directly to the gradle file. Did you cover that or is generated at some point if you import it as module?

Comment: check `+` button on top-right side. you can add dependency from there. once you add from there it will be added here.

Comment: In this particular case the main project I imported has this in its gradle file:

Comment: submodule
    // git submodule foreach git reset --hard
    // git submodule update --remote
    compile(project(':libnetcipher'))

Comment: Does this last option import the source?  I want to put breakpoints on the library source?

Comment: Check Third option Module Dependency which will import source code too.

Answer (score 2):

With you project currently loaded at Android Studio, use the menu File - Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies

Comment: You are right about importing as module however, I don't see File -Project Properties at all. Please correct your description so I can accept

Comment: What are you looking at man?  File->Project Properties ... Not seeing it.

Comment: Your answer was faster but no update for a long time!

Comment: Another issue, how do I import as project so that source shows up and I can put breakpoints on it?